# (control: AbstractControl) :

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, casting

Here a snippet of code extract from https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

```
/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
   return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
       const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
       return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

What is happening at the third line :

```
 return (control: AbstractControl): () => {}
```

Is it typing what the lambda function will return ? forbiddenNameValidator is supposed to return a ValidatorFn, should ValidatorFn be understood as ValidatorFonction ?

Comment: you can check my answer for the explanation.

Comment: I have also added link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you study the definition of `ValidatorFn` interface it has the following pattern -

```
interface ValidatorFn {
  (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null
}
```

which mean you can return any function which accepts an argument of type `AbstractControl` and returns either type `ValidationErrors` (which is actually a type alias) or `null`.

Here is the definition of `ValidationErrors`, it has the below index signature

```
type ValidationErrors = {
    [key: string]: any;
};
```

So your below example

```
return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => { 
 // other code 
 return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null; // check this line it's corresponds to ValidationErrors | null
}
```

actually returns a function of same signature that is compatible with the pattern of `ValidatorFn` interface.

```
(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => 
       {
         return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null; 
       }
```

check this link for reference : https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn#call

So the idea behind `forbiddenNameValidator` function is to return a function with same signature as the property of `ValidatorFn` interface